# How do I convert this Sublime snippet into a VS Code snippet?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, code-snippets

See below my attempt and result. The Sublime snippet first:

```
<snippet>
    <content>
        <![CDATA[<${1:p}>${2:$SELECTION}</${1/([^ ]+).*/$1/}>]]>
    </content>
    <tabTrigger>&lt;</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.xml</scope>
    <description>Long Tag</description>
</snippet>
```

and the keybinding:

```
{ "keys": ["super+shift+o"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/XML/long-tag.sublime-snippet" } },
```

What this does is the following:

1. Pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> will create an html tag `<p></p>` in with the `p` linked so you can start typing and it updates both sides. Pressing tab will place your cursor in the center of the tags.
2. Highlighting a section, then pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> will surround that section with the tags.

What I've managed to get trying on my own is the following in VS Code:

```
{
    "blank_tag": {
        "prefix": "<cmdso>",
        "body": [
            // "<$1>$2</$1>$3"
            "<${1:p}>${2:$SELECTION}</$1/([^ ]+).*}>"
        ],
        "description": "Adds a blank tag to use"
    }
}
```

This almost gets what I want but not quite. I'm not very good with regex but the result of this prints `<p></p/([^ ]+).*}>` I can remove that last bit of regex and it will get #1 satisfied. The #2 above is extremely helpful and I'd like to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm betting that last bit of regex is what allows you to highlight a section and surround it with the tags.

Can you help me fix this to work and satisfy #1 and #2?

Comment: Do you want to use the same keybinding to trigger both actions 1 and 2?  If so, see my answer below.  Your question is a little confusing, probably why you got 4 different answers.

Comment: Did any  of the answers work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok these are two different snippets, the first you already did so i'm going to speak about the second:

You want to surround a text in a tag based on a shortcut, you need two thing first to create the snippet, then to add the shortcut

This snippet when inserted will surround your text with a p tag, that changes immediately while you are writing.

```
"surround_tag": {
        "prefix": "<stag>",
        "body": [
            "<${1:p}>${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}</$1>"
        ],
        "description": "surround text by tag"
    }
```

Notice that we are using a specific variable called TM_SELECTED_TEXT, you can find more about these variables here, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Then add a keyboard shortcut to insert that snippet

```
{
    "key": "cmd+w cmd+t",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
      "name": "surround_tag", 
    }
  }

// in args here you can add a key langId to specify specific languages like
 "args": {
      "langId": "javascript",
      "name": "surround_tag", 
    }
```

You can find language identifiers here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers

Of course, you can also insert the snippet without the keyboard shortcut by using the insertSnippet command (CMD + Shift + P and then insertSnippet, then pick your one)

You can also use the following site to generate snippets for both vscode and sublime https://snippet-generator.app/

Answer (score 0):

You may fix your code using

```
"blank_tag": {
    "prefix": "<cmdso>",
    "body": [
        "<${1:p}>${2:$SELECTION}</${1/(\\S+).*/$1/}>"
    ],
    "description": "Adds a blank tag to use"
}
```

The `[^ ]` can be written as `\\S+` in the code, `\S+` matches 1 or more non-whitespace chars. The syntax is `${ID/pattern/replacement/flags}`, so you had an incomplete code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Sublime Text, you can use the [Atomizr](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Atomizr) package to convert snippets within the editor.

**Example:**

1. Install the package using Package Control
2. Open a Sublime Text snippet
3. Run the *Atomizr: Sublime Text to Visual Studio Code* command (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> on macOS)

To convert many files, it's probably more convenient to install the [CLI equivalent](https://github.com/idleberg/atomizr-cli) (requires [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/))

**Example:**

```sh
# Single conversion
atomizr example.sublime-snippet --target vscode

# Batch conversion
atomizr *.sublime-snippet --target vscode
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the **same keybinding** for **two different actions** as it seems you do, then you will have to find a way to differentiate between the then existing conditions so that the appropriate version is triggered properly.

In your case, that involves utilizing that in one situation you will start with **selected text**.  So we can use the `when` clause `editorHasSelection` to distinguish between the twp desired actions.

In your keybindings.json:

```
  {
    "key": "cmd+shift+O",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "<${1:p}>$0</$1>"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection"
  },

  {
    "key": "cmd+shift+O",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "<${1:p}>${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}</$1>"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
  }
```

**We see that only the second command will be triggered if there is a selection in the editor!!**

`!editorHasSelection` means if there is no selection, trigger this one.  Otherwise, we will trigger the other command.

Note that there is already a command also bound to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>: `workbench.action.gotoSymbol`  You should disable that command if you want to stick with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> as your triggers.  This will disable it:

```
{
  "key": "cmd+shift+O",
  "command": "-workbench.action.gotoSymbol"
},
```

Here is a demo of it working:

[image: demo of hasSelection snippet]